# Cmake: how to exclude and rename during Install directory

Tags: cmake, conditional-statements

I am working on a moderately sized project that uses cmake. (I know virtually nothing about working with cmake)

We are targeting both a 64bit and a 32 bit build.
I have a problem with some libraries that we can't build in 64 bit yet, so I have two versions of the same config file.

test.cfg, and test64.cfg (not actual names), where test64 has some modules commented out. The details of the contents of the files aren't super important.

These both live in a directory under /src/modules/moduleInQuestion/Config/

and they get installed by a CMakeLists.txt that has an install statement like this, all pretty standard stuff:

```
install(DIRECTORY Config
    DESTINATION ${INSTALL_ROOT_DIR}
)
```

With my newly added test64.cfg though, it'll install *both* of these files on our ./out/install/blah blah blah/Config directory. That's not what I want. I want either test.cfg, if its a 32 bit build, or test64.cfg (but renamed to test.cfg) if its a 64bit build.

I know I can wrap statements in `if(NOT CMAKE_CL_64) ... endif()`
but how do I specifically accomplish this "Select only one of these two files, depending on the build type, and in one of the two cases, rename it."

I'm not familiar enough with cmake to know the syntax. The documentation probably works a bit better as a reference than a learning tool.

I've tried having two seperate install statements (if(NOT CMAKE_CL_64), else()), and using EXCLUDE "test64.cfg" or EXCLUDE "test(\s*|\d+).cfg" and installing the specific file with an install(FILES...

Comment: "I've tried having two seperate install statements ..." - This seems to be the best way.